# How to get all content types having a certain field programmatically in Drupal 7?

Tags: php, drupal, module, drupal-7

I want to list all content types **(not nodes)** that have a special field for example "field_user_select".
How do I do this programmatically in drupal 7?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to use [field_read_instances](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--field--field.crud.inc/function/field_read_instances/7) to return all field instances of a given field_name. From that, get the entity bundles.

Comment: That is more or less the same function, except that field_read_* functions can automatically filter the returned information.

Answer (score 1):

I didn't found correct function, but you can create own function, take code from function field_ui_fields_list() in field_ui.admin.inc file, add argument for filtering by field name...